# How do determine Azure WAF rule that affect to my specific url

Tags: azure, azure-waf

My request got 403 when access to url like this format
`https://example.com/Test.aspx?param=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Fen-us%3F`

I have read [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-crs-rulegroups-rules?tabs=owasp30#crs931-30) but I not sure which rule prevented my request.

Anyone can show me:

- How do find exactly rule prevent my request
- Report prevented requests (I have looked at the log but nothing in there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled [WAF monitoring for application gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics) or [for Azure front door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-monitor), you should see the `ruleId` in the [Firewall log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#firewall-log). Please note that the logs are only saved hourly. You could get more details from [this blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/09/05/azure-application-gateway-waf-tuning/).

```
{
  "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/{subscriptionId}/RESOURCEGROUPS/{resourceGroupName}/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.NETWORK/APPLICATIONGATEWAYS/{applicationGatewayName}",
  "operationName": "ApplicationGatewayFirewall",
  "time": "2017-03-20T15:52:09.1494499Z",
  "category": "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog",
  "properties": {
    "instanceId": "ApplicationGatewayRole_IN_0",
    "clientIp": "104.210.252.3",
    "clientPort": "4835",
    "requestUri": "/?a=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22Hello%22);%3C/script%3E",
    "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
    "ruleSetVersion": "3.0",
    "ruleId": "941320",
    "message": "Possible XSS Attack Detected - HTML Tag Handler",
    "action": "Blocked",
    "site": "Global",
    "details": {
      "message": "Warning. Pattern match \"<(a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|audioscope|b|base|basefront|bdo|bgsound|big|blackface|blink|blockquote|body|bq|br|button|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|comment|dd|del|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|fn|font|form|frame|frameset|h1|head|h ...\" at ARGS:a.",
      "data": "Matched Data: <script> found within ARGS:a: <script>alert(\\x22hello\\x22);</script>",
      "file": "rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf",
      "line": "865"
    }
    "hostname": "40.90.218.100", 
    "transactionId": "AYAcUqAcAcAcAcAcASAcAcAc"
  }
}
```